# Shapefile will not load in QGIS but does in ArcGIS

Tags: shapefile

Using QGIS version 3.14.0-Pi on Windows 10.  I'm trying to download a shapefile (Layer, Create Layer, New Shapefile layer).  In the resulting dialog I use: File encoding UTF-8, Geometry type "Polygon" Add. dimensions EPSG:4269 - NAD83.  The original file is in NAD 83 UTM 12N.  The map I"m using is using EPSG:4326 WGS 84. When I say OK I get a message "The layer already exists.  Are you sure you want to overwrite the existing file?"  This happened the first time I tried to make the layer and occurs each time I make a new attempt.  When I say "yes" I get a new layer but nothing on the map and the attribute file is empty.  The same shapefile opens without any issues in ArcGIS.

Comment: Try Add Layer- Vector layer instead. Create makes a new one and thinks you want to overwrite the file. You can also just drag the .shp file in.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried both and got nothing.  Should I see some into in the attributes table or find some metadata somewhere to know that it exists?

Comment: Unfortunately you probably overwrote it when you where trying your original pathway. I bet if you tried to open it up again in ArcMap it would be empty there as well.